# Is there a way to use WhatsApp API with third party apps?

Tags: selenium, powerbi, whatsapp

I am new to using WhatsApp API. I am not sure but it seems that the api is for business users only. I want to use the api to send messages to users automatically based on a change in an app, (say PowerBI). I want to send updates regarding a report whenever a change is made and send it through whatsapp instead of email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, WhatsApp API is for business users. But, if you still looking for a WhatsApp bot I recommend Twilio, there are a lot of content about it in the internet. Check out this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQeFxdT3FGY&ab_channel=ProgrammingHero), It's using python and really easy.